# What is the difference between run process and start process in robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I have been reading up on the robot framework documentation but i am still  not very sure about the difference between start process and run process.

Do i need to use start process first then run it? Or i can just run process?

**For start process**

When i tried to run the following, the result was 1. It seems like it was calculating the number of process that has already started.

But i needed the result generated from calculation.robot.

```
${result} =     Start Process       calculation.robot       shell=True
```

**For run process**

Running something like this will generate error - permission denied

```
${result} =     Run Process     ${CURDIR}/calculation.robot
```

So i was just wondering what's the difference between the two.

Thank you!

Referenced to: https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Process.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `Start Process` does not return "results", this run process in the background so it returns identifier to running process.
- As opposite to `Start Process` the `Run Process` is waiting until process is completed.

So this difference cannot cause 'permission denied' and in the first case you will not see this error. And if you will use `Get Process Result` with handle that is returned by `Start Process` you will see the same error.